# Java import static method but not field

Tags: java, import, static

Take the following class for example:

```
public final class ClassName {
    public static final void TEST() {}
    public static final Object TEST;
}
```

Now, from another file, I want to `import static` `ClassName.TEST()`, but not `ClassName.TEST`.

How would I go about importing a method but not an identically named field, or vice versa?

Comment: Thinking that the best you can do is modify the field's scope to 'private' or package-level access (if the other file is outside of the current package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

`import` statements are completely a compile time concept. They don't do anything at run time. They allow you to use the simple name instead of a fully qualified name of types, or their members.

When you use

```
import static com.example.ClassName.TEST;
```

you're telling the compiler that you will want to use the simple name `TEST` from the type `com.example.ClassName` without qualification. What member it refers to doesn't matter*.

Java will be smart enough to determine if you mean to use the method or field based on its context (where and how it's used).

<sub>* except where [obscuring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2) might happen.</sub>